# how to implement mysql query first in nodejs? ( or to implement condition query first )

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

it is first time to use node js So this question can be very basic question. I tried to use callback instead of just returning value but I couldn't solve the problem.

I heard that mysql query is executed after other code in node js. 
**But I want to put (if condition) query in the middle of the code and check the condition before implementing codes below query.**

I am doing IoT thing ( sensor + android app + aws ubuntu server  with nodejs and using mysql for database )
I want to check if the sensor is working fine before adding data to server database.
So, **I put the code to check if sensors are working fine before storing data in database.** ( check by comparing the results from two sensors.  )

But the problem is that mysql query(to check if the sensors are right) is executed later than other code in node.js so I cannot check the condition in the middle.
How can I run condition query in the middle of the code and return any condition value?

```
app.get('/log', function(req, res){
        r = req.query;

        result_error = error_check(r.nickname);
        console.log("error check result"+result_error);


        insert_temp(r.nickname,r.left_num,r.right_num);
        //this function is called after error_check function, but when I saw the result, console.log in this function is called earlier than error_check function 

        res.end('OK:' + JSON.stringify(req.query));
});


function error_check(nickname){
        var sql = mysql.format('select sum(left_num) as left_sum, sum(right_num) as right_sum from temp where nickname = ?  and today_date = date(current_date());',nickname);
        var query = connection.query(sql,function(err,result){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Error check/// left_sum is "+result[0].left_sum + " right_sum is "+result[0].right_sum);
                if ((result[0].left_sum - result[0].right_sum >=30 )|| (result[0].right_sum - result[0].left_sum >=30 )){
                        console.log("Sensor is broken");
                        return 1;
                }
                else{
                        return -1;
                }
        });
        console.log(query);
}
/////////////////////////////but the result is
error check result undefined

(this is from insert_temp function! )nickname is ? left_num is ? right_num is ? gucheol 0 1

(this is from error_check function! this function is called before inset_temp function. error_check function is executed late...so I cannot check if sensor is wrong  )
Error check/// left_sum is 0 right_sum is 45
Sensor is broken
```

///but if we see the result from console/////

error check result **undefined**

(this is from insert_temp function! )nickname is ? left_num is ? right_num is ? gucheol 0 1

Error check/// left_sum is 0 right_sum is 45
Sensor is broken

(this is from error_check function! this function is called before insert_temp function. error_check function is executed late...so I cannot check if sensor is wrong  )

Comment: You have to pass `insert_temp(r.nickname,r.left_num,r.right_num);` as a callback function to `error_check` instead of calling it immediately. Or use a promise to do the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323 technically is a duplicate, but it's so much clientside ajax and so little node.js code that it might only confuse OP more if I flag it as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

`connection.query`  is a asynchronous function so that will execute in end of event loop.
Instant of `asynchronous` way you can use `synchronous` way using `util.promisify()`.

You can use like below to work your code,

```
app.get('/log', function(req, res){
        r = req.query;

        var sql = mysql.format('select sum(left_num) as left_sum, sum(right_num) as right_sum from temp where nickname = ?  and today_date = date(current_date());',r.nickname);
        var query = connection.query(sql,function(err,result){
                if (err) throw err;
                if ((result[0].left_sum - result[0].right_sum >=30 )|| (result[0].right_sum - result[0].left_sum >=30 )){
                        console.log("Sensor is broken");
                        res.end("NOT OK: Sensor is broken");
                }
                else{
                        insert_temp(r.nickname,r.left_num,r.right_num);
                        res.end('OK:' + JSON.stringify(req.query));
                }
        });
});
```

- Let me know if some error occur with this code.